# Two Network Adapters, One Prevents Other's Connection

Tags: networking, windows-xp, routing

Digged up the forums but couldn't find the same issue, so here comes the question:

My operating system is Windows XP. It has 2 network adapters.

1st: IP -> 10.54.88.55, Subnet -> 255.255.255.0, Default Gateway -> 10.54.88.1

2nd: IP -> 10.54.88.151, Subnet -> 255.255.252.0, Default Gateway -> 10.54.88.90

Adapters are connected to physically seperate networks. First adapter communicates with the devices in its network successfully. However, second one cannot communicate. When I unplug the ethernet cable from the first adapter, second one starts communicating. After plugging again, first one starts communicating and second one stops.

The first thing I have tried is giving higher priority to the second adapter but that didn't change anything. First adapter was communicating, second one was not.

When I added 255.255.255.0 to the second adapter's subnet mask list, it started communicating but the first adapter stopped.

Then I tried changing definitions in the routing table. I added a route entry using this command:

"route add 10.54.88.92 mask 255.255.255.255 10.54.88.151 metric 1 if 0x3"

It didn't worked while both adapters were connected. After unplugging the ethernet cable from the first adapter and running the command again everything started working. Both adapters were communicating with related networks successfully.

I made the entry static using "-p" option and restarted the machine. After restart, situation rewinded to beginning. First adapter was communicating while the second one was not.

There is something I should mention. When I printed the route table second adapter's interface was sometimes 0x3, sometimes 0x20003. That might be clue about the problem.

I know the easiest solution is changing the IP area of one of the networks but unfortunately this is not an option right now. I'm looking for a solution that can be applied via Windows settings. If that is not possible my last option is using a firewall for the second network.

I'm a total rookie about networking so I may have overlooked something obvious. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am rather tired atm, so double check this, but: I read this as:

## Network adaptor #1:

Network: 10.54.88.0 till 10.54.88.255 (256 IPs)
Of those 256 two are used for the network (10.54.88.0)  and for broadcast (10.54.88.255)
One of them use used by the default gateway (10.54.88.1)
One of them is in your by your NIC (10.54.88.55).

## Now up to your second configuration:

That uses this netmask: 255.255.252.0
Bitwise that netmask is 11111111.11111111.11111100.00000000

As you can see by the three zeros at the end you can have up to 1024 IPs.   (2<sup>10</sup>) and
the network range would be 10.54.88.0 till 10.54.91.255

A route add -host would be more specific and as I understand it it the more specific route should take precedence.

[Edit] Eh, just `route add` on windows. `route add -host` or `-net` on the rest of the world).

I'll leave this here for a few hours so you can read this, though after the corrections it is no longer a good answer and I intend to delete it.

Comment: I couldn't understand why you say netmask for second NIC is 255.255.255.248. It is defined as 255.255.252.0.
IPs do overlap indeed but networks are seperate so I think routing should solve the problem. For the second NIC, I only need to communicate with 10.54.88.92. That's why I added it to route table but didn't work.

Comment: Now that I am back I can't understand it either. I'll fix that in my post.  Regarding communication only with 10.54.88.92, what are the setting on the other host. If it has a different idea about broadcast then it might now be answering arp requests (though and `arp -a` should quickly tell you if that is the case or not.)

Comment: Actually, 10.54.88.92 is not a computer. It is an industrial device (called PLC) and it doesn't have complicated settings for networking so there is no way that it can only answer the arp requests. As I mentioned in the original post, I can reach it from the second NIC, only when the first NIC is unplugged.

Comment: What happens with your default gateway when you unplug the first NIC. (Note that you only have one active default gateway, which is not tied to a NIC but is a general setting).

Comment: I didn't check the default gateway and as I'm in another city right now, it is only possible to check it next saturday. If the default gateway is something general then does it mean I should enter it only one of the NICs?
Also I'm really suspicious about the interface number changes (0x3 and 0x20003 issue). That might be the reason why routing is not working. I'll try with another NIC next time.

Comment: A default gateway is a system wide setting and it is not tied to any specific NIC.  (There can only be one default).  Googling that might bring up multiple default gateways since it is sensible to change the default gateway to a backup if the first one becomes unreachable. But the basic routing mechanisme is:
1) Use the most specific route to a target. (e.g. most restricting netmask)
2) If there is none use a generic route.
3) If all else fails use the single default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Gateways can indeed be tied to specific NICs. I can setup two separate networks in my home, and have one computer attached to both of them (like the asker's situation) if I manually set the network configuration, each NIC has to have a default gateway specific to the network that NIC is attached to.

So for example:

Network 1: 192.168.0.x Default gateway would normally be 192.168.0.1 subnet 255.255.255.0
Network 2: 192.168.137.x default gateway would normally be 192.168.137.1 subnet 255.255.255.0

looking at your configuration, it's possible that windows is confused. 10.54.88.x (forget subnet for a moment)

two NICs using the same first 3 octets (x.x.x) of the IP network IP addresses are identical, but each NIC is configured with a different default gateway.

If you're trying to get one network to see, and communicate with the other, combine them all together, remove the second gateway (or turn off it' DHCP server), and have the first gateway assign all IPs via it's DHCP protocol. If you only disable the DHCP protocol of the second gateway device, make sure you attach it to your main network via a network port, and NOT it's Internet port. All subnets should be identical in this configuration.

I'll give an example using my own network setup

Router 1:
IP Address: 192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Network gateway: Yes
DHCP Enabled: Yes
Serving Internet: Yes (Served to gateway's internet port)
DHCP Addresses: 192.168.1.5-200 (195 devices allowable)

Router 2:
IP address: 192.168.1.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Network gateway: no
DHCP enabled: no
Serving internet: No (Attached to first router via standard network port from router 1 to standard network port on router 2)
DHCP addresses: N/A

Any device attached to either router in this configuration can see any other devices that are supposed to be visible. All devices are able to get internet from the main gateway.

NOTE: If you're simply trying to use a computer to allow a second network to have internet, you can use Internet Connection Sharing. All network devices will be able to see that computer, but devices from network 1 will not be able to see or share with devices on network 2.